# Calling async method from view model's constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, mvvm

I'm building an MVVM Light WPF app in Visual Studio 2015 with Entity Framework 6. The app has numerous view models that call `async` methods for initialization. Here's a sample view model:

```
public class MyViewModel : MyViewModelBase
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        PopulateParameters();

        // Other code...
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ParametersViewModel> 
        Parameters { get; private set; } = 
            new ObservableCollection<ParametersViewModel>();

    private async void PopulateParameters()
    {
        var service = new MyDataService();
        Parameters.Clear();
        foreach(var parameter in await service.GetParameters())
            Parameters.Add(parameter);      
    }
    // Other methods and properties
}
```

In `MyDataService` class, I have this method:

```
public async Task<ParametersViewModel> GetParameters()
{
    using (var context = new MyEntities())
    {
        var query = (from param in context.Parameters
            select new ParametersViewModel
            {
                // Populate ParametersViewModel properties here...
            }
            );
        return await Task.Run(() => query);
    }
}
```

Note that the view model's constructor is calling the `async void` method `PopulateParameters()`. This is very bad programming and I'd like to change it. However, I'm not sure how. I can't inject the necessary data into all my view models; some have to perform their own initialization, much of which involve calls to `async` methods.

How do I change the above code to conform to best practices when async methods are called from a view model's constructor? Thanks.

**Update**: Ensure you bind to the `.Result` of the value returned from `NotifyTask.Create()`. Took me a while to figure that out. More on that here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx

Comment: If you talk about best practices - what would you do when your PopulateParameters will throw an exception? And this can and will happen, because it talks to remote service (or to database).

Comment: Why not make `PopulateParameters` properly return `Task` and call it synchronously from the constructor using `.Wait()`? Am I missing something obvious here? One thing that seems intuitively obvious is that a constructor should never call `async` code that initializes the object -- so either make the initialization sync, or make it happen somewhere other than the constructor.

Comment: @Evk, thanks! You're right. How do I capture the exception and handle it gracefully? I wanted to include that question above but didn't :)

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Should the c'tor call an `Init()` method that calls `PopulateParameters` async, or would that be problematic too?

Comment: It depends on who\what calls that constructor. If that is done by you - reasonable to create static factory method, make constructor private, and create AND initialize new instance in that factory method. Then the caller can in turn await this method and handle exception.

Comment: Don't mix async contexts with your view's model, unless you await the response before rendering your view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a blog post describing several approaches to "[async constructors](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html)".

In this case, though, it looks like what you'd really want is [async data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx). Using the `NotifyTask` type from my [Mvvm.Async library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async) would look like this:

```
public NotifyTask<ObservableCollection<ParametersViewModel>>
    Parameters { get; private set { /* with notify, such as RaisePropertyChanged() */ } }

public MyViewModel()
{
  Parameters = NotifyTask.Create(() => GetParametersAsync(),
      new ObservableCollection<ParametersViewModel>());
  // Other code...
}

private async Task<ObservableCollection<ParametersViewModel>> GetParametersAsync()
{
  var service = new MyDataService();
  var result = new ObservableCollection<ParametersViewModel>();
  foreach(var parameter in await service.GetParameters())
      result.Add(parameter);
  return result;
}
```

The `NotifyTask<T>` wrapper provides several data-bindable properties, such as `Result` containing the observable collection, `IsNotCompleted` for showing loading indicators, and `IsFaulted`/`ErrorMessage` for data-binding error conditions (if you want to).

Comment: Thanks, @StephenCleary. I saw your blog last Friday and was wondering how to implement the examples you've got there. A follow-up: How do I catch exceptions when the db is unavailable, so my `service` object call bombs out?

Comment: @Alex: `NotifyTask<T>` assumes that any exceptions escaping from `GetParametersAsync` will be handled via data binding (i.e., `IsFaulted` and friends). If you want to handle them manually, you'd want to catch them in `GetParametersAsync`.

Comment: Thanks, @StephenCleary. How do you bind to the `IsFaulted` or `ErrorMessage`? Are they on the `Parameters` object? Also, the API Docs link throws a 500 error: http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Nito.Mvvm.Async

Comment: @Alex: Yes. If you follow my link for async data binding, it uses a very similar pattern (`NotifyTask<T>` is an updated `NotifyTaskCompletion<T>`).

Comment: Is it possible to include the Mvvm.Async library in my project via NuGet?

Comment: @Alex: Yes, it's [available on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.Mvvm.Async). I'm not sure what the 500 error is about, but you can use the [API docs for the last version](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Nito.Mvvm.Async/1.0.0-beta-1) for now.

Comment: Thanks again, @StephenCleary. I'm going to install Beta 2 from NuGet :)

Comment: Need a little more help, @StephenCleary: I can't seem to include the library in my view model with a `using` statement. It's included in my references, but how do you then include `NotifyTask` in your code?

Comment: @Alex: If you installed `Nito.Mvvm.Async`, you should be able to just do a `using Nito.Mvvm;`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113933/discussion-between-alex-and-stephen-cleary).

Comment: Sorry to keep bugging you, @StephenCleary. Got everything working, but it doesn't like the `with notify;` -- it says `cannot resolve symbol 'with'`

Comment: @Alex: That's just placeholder text meaning "raise `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` here".

Comment: Thanks, @StephenCleary. It had me confused for the longest time! Updated answer to clarify. By the way, I don't believe you need `PropertyChanged` on an `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: @Alex: The `PropertyChanged` is for the `Parameters` property. The type of the property is immaterial. If it's only set during the constructor, then you can skip the `PropertyChanged`, but as a general rule I put it in all my VMs unless the property is actually a get-only property.

Comment: It's only set in the constructor; in fact, all my VMs behave this way. Thanks for this cool library, @StephenCleary!